# C++: how to exclude symmetric pairs in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I wrote program that sums the first and last indices of a vector. That is, it prints `v1[k] + v1[v1.size() - 1 - k]` where `k` iterates over the indices. If the user inputs an even size vector, I pick up the symmetric pairs; for example, the program will print `v1[0] + v1[last]` and `v1[last] + v1[0]` but these two are the exact same so I would like to exclude them. The code I have written is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  vector<int> v1;  // initialize v1 as an empty int vector
  int i = 0;       // initialize i as int 0
  // prompt user for inputs
  cout << "Enter in a set of integers:" << endl;
  while (cin >> i) {
    v1.push_back(i);  // at run time populate the vector with ints
  }
  for (unsigned k = 0; k != v1.size() && k != v1.size() - 1 - k; ++k) {
    cout << "The sum of the " << k << " and " << v1.size() - 1 - k
         << " indices are:" << v1[k] + v1[v1.size() - 1 - k] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

After the prompt, if I enter in `1,2,3,4` and hit <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to end the `while` loop, the output is:

```
The sum of the 0 and 3 indices are:5
The sum of the 1 and 2 indices are:5
The sum of the 2 and 1 indices are:5
The sum of the 3 and 0 indices are:5
```

Comment: Hint: What is the index you want to stop at, as a function of `v1.size()`?

Comment: @Barry I would want to stop at `v1.size()/2` so I could write `k != v1.size()/2`

Comment: So try that with even and odd vector sizes and see if it works.

Comment: @Barry I did prior to commenting. Would you like to make your comment an answer?

Comment: @barry I would like to give you credit for your comment since it came first and answered my question. Do you not want to make an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating over the entire vector, just iterate up to the middle of it.

```
for (unsigned k = 0; k < (v1.size() + 1) / 2; ++k) {
    cout << "The sum of the " << k << " and " << v1.size() - 1 - k
         << " indices are:" << v1[k] + v1[v1.size() - 1 - k] << endl;
}
```